# random image background with javascript with setInterval

Tags: javascript, css, arrays, loops

How to get a random image background for our webpage by Set interval?

Example: I have an image choice as `imgg` variable

```
let imgg = [ "red", "pink", "yellow", "brown", "white"]

let foto = document.querySelector(".container")
```

Now I want to set that background .container by those array color and want to setInterval, and keep changing without stop, 
can anyone give me a suggestion?

Comment: Sure, please read about [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) at MDN.

Comment: Simply typing your question title into Google would have gotten you lots of results already. Please try and research basic questions like this before asking them here next time.

Answer (score 1):

Use from this code:

```js
var images=['http://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/stunning-images-of-the-space.jpg',
            'https://www.nasa.gov/sites/default/files/styles/image_card_4x3_ratio/public/thumbnails/image/pia20645_main.jpg?itok=dLn7SngD',
            'http://24space.ru/uploads/posts/2014-12/1418220047_asteroid.jpg',
            'https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcT-1jIpSolSoVubMTdKYhIJyQxqEOK66TT01y2PJXrddMsPz2dx'];
var url=0;
setInterval(function(){
   url+=1;
  if(url==4){
    url=0;
  }
  document.body.style.backgroundImage = 'url('+images[url]+')';
  document.body.style.backgroundRepeat = "no-repeat";
},5000);
```